# How do I proxy requests for static files on my node server to my react development server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have a node.js server that serves the built static files of my `create-react-app` at `/admin`. The problem is that anytime I make a change to my react app I have to build the files over again to see the updates. Instead, I'd like to proxy requests for my frontend at `/admin` to my dev server that comes with `create-react-app`, running at `localhost:3000`, because this would allow for a much faster development experience.

This is what my server looks like now:

```
// app.ts
...
const app: Koa = new Koa();

app.use(mount('/admin', serve(__dirname + '/build')));
...
```

And this is what I tried:

```
import proxy from 'koa-better-http-proxy';

const app: Koa = new Koa();

app.use(
  mount(
    '/admin',
    proxy('localhost:3000', {})
  )
)
```

What ends up happening is the requests for static files still go out and the response gives an index.html file but the JS doesn't seem to run and it gives me errors:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

I've also played around with the proxy header settings to adjust `content-type` to `application/json` but I had no success there either.

Due to the environment, I cannot just run the node server in one terminal and the react app in another. The request comes from a verified 3rd party and must go through my node server first before being served the frontend portion of my app.